# uglifyJs Application needed(JavaScript Obfuscator)

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, minify, uglifyjs

I want to know if there is any version of uglifyJS in a windows application mode(not web based app) or maybe another good application that is not web based.

This is the [uglifyJS](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs) site.

Thank you

Comment: Haven't tried none of the following: http://www.varhammer.com, http://www.stunnix.com/prod/jo/, try to google a bit

Comment: I have just used uglifyJS website and I'm satisfied with the app but I need a none web based app.

Comment: The site posted are windows application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [NodeJS](https://npmjs.org) and use the official [uglify-js npm package](https://npmjs.org/package/uglify-js). It's the way UglifyJS and a lot other JS libs are meant to be used in an offline fashion.